# igraph0.7.0 write.graph as edgelist

Tags: igraph

I am using igraph0.7.0. I do not understand the node number of each edge:

```
g = graph.ring(3)
write.graph( g, format='edgelist', file='./temp.tsv' )
```

The result in './temp.tsv':

```
0 1
0 2
1 2
```

Each row should be the node number of an edge, why the number has been misused by 1?
I know in igraph0.6.x, node number starts from 0. But for igraph0.7.0 it starts from 1. Is this a bug?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this is not a bug. The edgelist format uses zero-based indexing even from R to be compatible with the Python interface and the C core, which also use zero-based indexing. (Otherwise an edge list saved from R would be loaded incorrectly when someone uses the Python interface or the C core directly).